# Prediction of Pure Premium with GLM including offset

Tags: r, offset, prediction, glm, predict

I'm modeling a pure premium which is equal to cost loss/ exposure by using a glm with an offset term.
The model is written in R as:

```
glm(cost loss ~ X +offset(log(exposure)), family=tweedie(var.power=1.41, link.power=0)
```

My question is, in R, what does `predict.glm(fit, train, type="response")` return with an offset?

- The cost lost? and in this case I have to divide with exposure to get the predicted Pure Premium?
- Or the Pure Premium by supposing the exposure is already taken in the prediction?

When I use `predict.glm(fit, train, type="response")` I don't know if I get the Pure Premium or the cost loss. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe `predict.glm` should return the predicted mean response which in your case is the cost loss. To get the predicted mean pure premium, it's my understanding that you would divide that by the offset, though I'm not entirely sure of this as I've never used the tweedie family though I did read somewhere that `link.power` = 0 is equivalent to a log-link. 
Also, to include exposure as an offset you would need to replace it with `offset(log(exposure))`, otherwise it's treated as a predictor whose coefficient need not be fixed at 1.

Comment: Thansk you @NicChr for your answer. Yeah i forgot the offset term in my question. I just modify it.